# Why is the Windows 11 terminal pushing escape sequences to Tmux?

Tags: windows, ssh

Ssh's RemoteCommand facility can be used to automatically create/attach a tmux session, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838493/5368599).  In Windows, my sessions intermittently see the escape sequence ^`0;10;1c` or ^`[[>1;1c`, showing like this in my terminal:

[image]

This behaviour seems restricted to Windows 11, with both the Terminal and Console Host applications. It does not seem to occur on Windows 10 on any variant of cmd.exe.  I'm presently working around it by running with the W11 Console Host in legacy mode, but I'd much rather use Windows Terminal.

How can I keep these escape sequences out of my tmux sessions?

**Original question text with bad assumptions below:**

*(I now believe this is an incorrect assumption, based on the response from @user1686 below).*

OpenSSH for Windows (including the current beta 9.2p1) seems to push some extra characters that look like escape sequences.  In a given command window, the first ssh session has garbage inserted, such that my fresh tmux session looks like the image below.  Same deal from cmd, powershell, and cygwin terminal.  This does *not* happen if the remote command is absent, or a virgin `bash` command.  Mysteriously, it also doesn't happen on the second, fourth, etc ssh commands.

Comment: I'm also getting this *every* time I start a new Tmux session on Win 11 terminal using WSL Ubuntu 22. Creating new shells (panes) do not see it. I saw [this](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible/issues/61) and tried this: `set -sg escape-time 10` in my `tmux.conf`, which seems to have solved it.

Comment: Thanks, and glad it worked for you!  This improved things a little for me, but I still get it about 1/2 the time.  I tried with escape-time of 0, 10, and 50.  I've subscribed to the link, hopefully someone will post a more general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the terminal's *response* to an `ESC [ c` "Request terminal attributes" that was issued by the remote program.

(`\033[c` "Request terminal attributes" is one of several information requests that tmux outputs to the terminal, expecting to receive similar responses as input coming from the terminal (normally they would be invisibly consumed by tmux, just like special-key sequences are).

I'm not able to reproduce this with tmux 3.3a nor with 3.2a.

> Mysteriously, it also doesn't happen on the second, fourth, etc ssh commands.

Your remote command is specifically written to start a new tmux session the first time but attach to an existing session on the second, fourth, etc. connections. It's natural that they would show different behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful!  It appears that this only occurs on Windows 11, with both the Terminal and Console Host applications.  It does *not* appear to occur with the Console Host in legacy mode, nor with Windows 10 on any variant of cmd.exe I tried.   I'll update my question to avoid misleading others.

Comment: As commented against the question you may find `set -sg escape-time 10` in your `tmux.conf` prevents this from continuing.